# How to enable 'allow_drop_detached' in system.settings?

Tags: clickhouse

What should I specify in *config.xml* to enable (set to 1) the **allow_drop_detached** parameter in the *system.settings* table?

It cannot be changed by 'alter table' request.

Error message:

```
Code: 344. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Cannot execute query: DROP DETACHED PART is disabled (see allow_drop_detached setting).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be defined in *user.xml* not *config.xml*.

---

Create an arbitrary file with required changes (here it is *query.settings.xml*) in directory */etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/*:

```sh
nano /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/query.settings.xml
```

with content (here this param is set only for *default*-profile):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<yandex>
    <profiles>
        <default>
            <!-- Allow ALTER TABLE ... DROP DETACHED PART[ITION] ... queries. -->
            <allow_drop_detached>1</allow_drop_detached>
        </default>
    </profiles>
</yandex>
```

Save this file and check that param is set to 1:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM system.settings
WHERE name = 'allow_drop_detached'
/*
┌─name────────────────┬─value─┬─changed─┬─description─────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─min──┬─max──┬─readonly─┐
│ allow_drop_detached │ 1     │       1 │ Allow ALTER TABLE ... DROP DETACHED PART[ITION] ... queries │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │        0 │
└─────────────────────┴───────┴─────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────────┘
*/
```

---

The alternate ways to set this param are:

1. query level

```sql
ALTER TABLE table
    DROP DETACHED PARTITION '2020-04-01'
SETTINGS allow_drop_detached = 1;
```

2. session level

```sql
SET allow_drop_detached = 1;

ALTER TABLE table
    DROP DETACHED PARTITION '2020-04-01';
```